# Cannot reuse (inherit) HMENU/TMENU and reset values like linkWrap or typolink.ATagParams

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I created a language selector like that:

```
lib.language = HMENU
lib.language {
    special = language
    special.value = 0,1,2
    special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
    wrap =
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        noBlur = 1
        NO = 1
        NO {
            linkWrap = |
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.override = deutsch || english || français
            stdWrap {
                typolink {
                    parameter.data = page:uid
                    additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=1 || &L=2
                    ATagParams = class="dropdown-item" hreflang="de-DE" || class="dropdown-item" hreflang="en-GB" || class="dropdown-item" hreflang="fr-FR"
                    addQueryString = 1
                    addQueryString.exclude = L,id,cHash,no_cache
                    addQueryString.method = GET
                    useCacheHash = 1
                    no_cache = 0
                    forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                }
            }
        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT.ATagParams = class="dropdown-item active"
    }
}
```

For mobile I wanted that menu to be inherited, but with a different linkWrap (and classes):

```
lib.languageMobile < lib.language
lib.languageMobile.1.NO {
    linkWrap = <li class="1"><div>|</div></li>
    stdWrap.typolink {
        ATagParams = class="btn btn-sub" hreflang="de-DE" || class="btn btn-sub" hreflang="en-GB" || class="btn btn-sub" hreflang="fr-FR"
        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        wrap = <span>|</span>
    }
}
lib.languageMobile.1.ACT.ATagParams = class="btn btn-sub active"
```

But all values specifically reset for `lib.languageMobile` are not rendered in frontend. The TypoScript Object Browser does show the values as set though.
I didn't find anything about, that resetting values for inherited HMENU/TMENU does not apply, or that there are known issues like that.

I am using latest TYPO3 8.7 LTS: 8.7.4.

Can someone point out, what I am missing or doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO: your code should work. Try to make a copy and check if that works to see if something else breaks your code. Over the years I stopped using { } when I want to override small parts and write out the complete line every time - although not necessary, this helps with syntax error a lot.;;; Did you check the output or the TypoScript Object browser, the latter is a better choice;;; And my most stupid experience: is lib.language defined first? I once included TS-files in the wrong order.

Comment: Aside from what NextThursday already said (order of statements): do you use conditions? and have you noticed your copy for `lib.language` (`ACT < .NO`) will not be executed for `lib.languageMobile`. All changes you have done to `lib.languageMobile.1.NO` will not apply to `lib.languageMobile.1.ACT`. You need to repeat that copy statement after you changed `lib.languageMobile.1.NO`

Comment: @NextThursday As I wrote, the TS Object Browser shows the correctly (re-)setted values. Both are defined in the same file with `lib.language` before `lib.languageMobile`. When I copy/paste the exact code and change the lines I want to re-set, everything works as expected.  ---  
@BerndWilkeπφ I don't use any conditions. I know I'm missing `ACT < .NO` but as long as `NO`s values aren't re-set I didn't bother yet. But thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Since @BerndWilkeπφ brought me on the right track, I wanted to share what resolved it for me.

Because I have indeed all available language set in the language selector, but not all pages are fully translated to all languages yet. So I stumbled upon the usage of `USERDEF1` and `USERDEF2`.
When I added them to `lib.language` I changed `lib.languageMobile` to:

```
lib.languageMobile < lib.language
lib.languageMobile.1 {
    NO {
        linkWrap = <li class="1"><div>|</div></li>
        stdWrap.typolink {
            ATagParams = class="btn btn-sub" hreflang="de-DE" || class="btn btn-sub" hreflang="en-GB" || class="btn btn-sub" hreflang="fr-FR"
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            wrap = <span>|</span>
        }
    }
    ACT < .NO
    ACT.ATagParams = class="btn btn-sub active"
    USERDEF1 < .NO
    USERDEF2 < .ACT
}
```

After that the mobile language selector was rendered as intended.